# How can I use the same for loop instead of three loops

Tags: java

I am creating a method that goes through a list of objects that are Airplanes which all have a takeoff, fly, and land method.  I created this method by making 3 different for loops that executes each method separately.  Is there anyway to use the same for loop to remove the redundant code?

```
protected void simulate() {
    for(Aircraft obj : vehicles) {
        obj.takeoff();
    }
    for(Aircraft obj : vehicles) {
        obj.fly();
    }
    for(Aircraft obj : vehicles) {
        obj.land();
    }
```

Comment: do you really need a fly() method ? You could remove an iteration if takeoff() completing successfully was that same as calling fly() ?

Comment: @newbie, this isn't really relevant to the question. Anyway, maybe OP doesn't want to fly somewhere and not land on the same spot.

Comment: then you just make obj.flyfrom = obj.flyto and it does take out a whole iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove redundant code, you could

```
vehicles.foreach(Aircraft::takeOff)
vehicles.foreach(Aircraft::fly)
vehicles.foreach(Aircraft::land)
```

You however need three loops if you want to make them fly together.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but not very useful to get everyhing done in one loop, e. g. using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html. But that would add relatively much complexity in some other class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use separate `for` loops.

If you are looking for a shorter code and you are using `java 8+` you can do:

```
vehicles.forEach(Aircraft::takeoff); 
vehicles.forEach(Aircraft::fly);
vehicles.forEach(Aircraft::land);
```